# How to merge multiple file with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have 2 files

file1:

```
Fruits
Mango
Orange
Banana
```

file2:

```
Cost
100
80
40
```

expected output:

```
Fruits    Cost
Mango  100
Orange  80
Banana  40
```

How can I do this with `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use awk:

```
awk '{print $0, ((getline x < "-") == 1 ? x : "")}' file1 < file2
```

The return value of `getline` is tested (it returns 1 for success) and value printed accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Use `paste` instead of `awk` for this.  e.g.

```
$ paste file1 file2
Fruits  Cost
Mango   100
Orange  80
Banana  40
```

The default output column separator for `paste` is a TAB.  You can use the `-d` option to use commas, colons, semi-colons or whatever you want instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using the  `Perl` utility we can paste the two files side by side as shown:

```
perl -pe '
  ($_ .= <STDIN>) =~ s/\n/ /;
' file1 < file2
```

---

Using the `GNU sed` versuon of stream editor, we can paste the two files as:

```
sed -e 'R file2' file1| sed -e 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

---

using `python` utility we paste the two files by means of the map function:

```
python3 -c 'import sys
file1,file2 = sys.argv[1:]
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
  print(*list(map(lambda x,y: f"{x.rstrip()} {y}",f1,f2)),sep="",end="")
' file1 file2
```